# How to launch a certain activity of an Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I would like to launch, from my app, two specific activities A_Activity and B_Activity from apps Aapp and Bapp
I inserted two buttons and in the two OnClickListener I wrote

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction("com.Acompany.Aapp.A_Activity");
ctx.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction("com.Bcompany.Bapp.B_Activity");
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Moreover I added to AndroidManifest.xml the following lines

```
<activity
    android:name="com.Acompany.Aapp.A_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.Acompany.Aapp.A_Activity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.Bcompany.Bapp.B_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.Bcompany.Bapp.B_Activity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But my app crashes and in the logcat I read "No Activity found to handle Intent"
Where is my mistake?

EDIT: More precisely the two activities are not in my own app

Comment: What happens if you just use: 
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
FirstActivity.this.SecondActivity(myIntent);

Comment: This line is very confusing: `I would like to launch, from my app, two specific activities A_Activity and B_Activity from *apps Aapp and Bapp*` Both activities you would like to launch are in the same app as the activity you are launching from?

Comment: I have 3 apps... MyApp with the two buttons and A_app and B_app with the activities I would like to launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More precisely the two activities are not in my own app

You should investigate target app's manifest file first, to check if these activities are available to others by being exported or offering publicly accessible intent filters. It looks you may simply be not allowed to do what you attempt to.

Comment: how can i understand if these app allow me to do that?

Comment: you need to check if these activies are exported or offer intent-filter that is not restricted

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. For your home activity(first launch activity) do like this in your manifest file.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.Acompany.LaunchHomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.Acompany.LaunchHomeActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.Acompany.Aapp.A_Activity">

</activity>
<activity android:name="com.Bcompany.Bapp.B_Activity">

</activity>
```

don't include `<intent-filter>` to all activities

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myFirstClass.this, MySecondClassA.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Class B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myFirstClass.this, MySecondClassB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```